# JavaScript /Jquery : A for loop function with some special usage

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, handlebars.js

This application have 2 components, a HTML page which contain some element and a JavaScript to generate buttons.

I will try to give out a simplify example in the question for now, but if there's something unclear then i would upload the full code later.

**I am using HandleBar.js to generate different contents in the html but don't worry if you don't have any idea about this plugin i will make another non-handlebar.js version.**

Consider the Html part looks like below:

**HandleBar.js version**

```
    //example:
    //{{feedId}} = 0t454g465754754h456
    //{{url}} = www.jegdo.co.uk


    {{each}}
    <div class="feedIdChecker">{{feedId}}</div>

    <div class="{{feedId}}-EditRegionUrl" >{{url}}</div>

    <button class="output-{{feedId}}"><a href="javascript:void(0)">Output</a></button>
   {{/each}}
```

Then i have a JQuery function which would output the url

```
var feedId = $(".feedIdChecker").html();

            $('".output-'+feedId+'"').click(function(){
                var postUrl = $('".'+feedId+'-EditRegionUrl"').html();
                console.log(postUrl );
        });
     });
    }
```

I found there's no way to identify which button is which. Since i need to declare the `var feedID` outside the button, it would always get the first feedID it founds and append to all buttons, how may i solve it? Please tell me if this question is confuse, i will try to explain it in a better way.

There's lots of people trying to help me but it seem i need to give out some more details in order for better understanding:

Javascript:

```
    var initRegionEdit = function(){

            var feedId = $(".feedIdChecker").html();
            $(".CTHK").click(function(){
                  var postUrl = ($(this).prev('div').html());
               })
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="EditRegionUrl" >{{url}}</div>
<div class="feedIdChecker">{{feedId}}</div>
    {{#if region}}
                            <span class="dropdown"><i class="fa fa-map-marker" aria-hidden="true" style="color:gray;"></i>
                                <span class="result-date result-date-region" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">{{region}}
                                <span class="caret"></span></span>
                                <ul class="dropdown-menu" style="min-width:100px;text-align:center;"> 
                                  <li class="CTHK" data-url="{{url}}" style=" margin-top: 0px !important;margin-bottom: 0px !important;"><a href="javascript:void(0)">Hong Kong</a></li><div class="divider"></div>
                                  <li class="CTTW" style=" margin-top: 0px !important;margin-bottom: 0px !important;"><a href="javascript:void(0)">Taiwan</a></li><div class="divider"></div>
                                </ul>
                            </span>
                            {{/if}}
```

I wish above information can help

Comment: you just want the url of the button clicked or am i mistaken?

Comment: `$(this).prevAll(".feedIdChecker").eq(0).html()` - jQuery is all about DOM traversal...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So when you select `$(".feedIdChecker")` you actually get an array of all matching elements, but as soon as you call `.html` it only gets you the first. So to solve your issue we need to loop over all the `$(".feedIdChecker")`s like so:

```
$(".feedIdChecker").each(function(i, e) {
    var feedID = $(e).html();
    $('.output-'+feedID).click(function(){
        var postUrl = $("." + feedID + "-EditRegionUrl").html();
        console.log(postUrl);
    });
});
```

This will attach the click handler to each of the buttons.

Answer (score 2):

You could use the handlebars.js each/index feature to do this:

```
<button id="whatever-{{@index}}"
        class="output-{{feedId}}">
    <a href="javascript:void(0)">Output</a>
</button>
```

I'm assuming you need an answer on how to apply a unique id to each button, not how to bind click handlers to them (which other people have answered anyway)

Answer (score 2):

Can you just put url in the button and a generic class:

```
<button class="output-{{feedId}} btn-class" data-url="{{url}}"><a href="javascript:void(0)">Output</a></button>
```

and then

```
$('.btn-class').click(function(){
                console.log($(this).data('url') );
        });
```

Or even just without changing your markup at all

```
 $("button").click(function(){
                console.log($(this).prev('div').text());
        });
```

Comment: I tried your method but it return nothing, the console said undefined

Comment: i had forgotten to put single quotes in url See here both methods working https://jsfiddle.net/093kbu07/

Answer (score 2):

May this version be quicker and with less code.

```js
$('[class*=output-]').click(function() {
  var feedId = this.className.split("-")[1];
  var postUrl = $('.EditRegionUrl-' + feedId).html();
  alert(postUrl);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="feedIdChecker">1</div>
<div class="EditRegionUrl-1" >URL1</div>
<button class="output-1">Output1</button>

<div class="feedIdChecker">2</div>
<div class="EditRegionUrl-2" >URL2</div>
<button class="output-2">Output2</button>
```